# fetch dictionary from arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, arraylist

```
protected Dictionary<string , string> xmlList = new Dictionary<string , string>();
protected System.Collections.ArrayList list = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
```

I have stored the dictionary in an arraylist like this..

```
    xmlList.Add( "image" , "images/piece1.png" );
    xmlList.Add( "description" , " Experience why entertainment is more amazing with Xbox."            );
    xmlList.Add( "title" , "Downloads" );
    list.Add( xmlList );
    xmlList.Clear();
    xmlList.Add( "image" , "images/piece2.png" );
    xmlList.Add( "description" , "Limited-time offer: Buy Office now, get the next version free.*" );
    xmlList.Add( "title" , "Security & Updates" );
    list.Add( xmlList );
```

How can I access each element of the dictionary from the arraylist?

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
    foreach(Dictionary<string , string> itemList in list)
        {
        Response.Write( itemList["image"] );
        }
   } 
%>
```

and that gives me the same result 'images/piece2.png' two times..

I couldn't do

```
foreach(Dictionary<string , string> itemList in list[i])
    {
    Response.Write( itemList["image"] );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 protected Dictionary<string, string> xmlList;
    protected System.Collections.ArrayList list = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

 xmlList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        xmlList.Add("image", "images/piece1.png");
        xmlList.Add("description", " Experience why entertainment is more amazing with Xbox.");
        xmlList.Add("title", "Downloads");
        list.Add(xmlList);
        xmlList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        xmlList.Add("image", "images/piece2.png");
        xmlList.Add("description", "Limited-time offer: Buy Office now, get the next version free.*");
        xmlList.Add("title", "Security & Updates");
        list.Add(xmlList);

        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> itemList in list)
        {
            Response.Write(itemList["image"]);
            Response.Write("<br>");
        }
```

Comment: it gives me following error message

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 1):

1) Use generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of `ArrayList`:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> xmlList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

2) If you want to have two separate dictionaries in the list, you need to create two of them, otherwise you have two references to one and the same dictionary. So:

```
 list.Add(xmlList);
 xmlList = new Dictionary<string, string>(); //instead of xmlList.Clear();
 //...
 list.Add(xmlList);
```

3) Now you can do the following to iterate through the list of dictionaries:

```
 foreach (Dictionary<string, string> d in list)
 {
     //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this snippet to iterate through each dictionary on the list and fetch each element in the dictionary.

```
foreach(Dictionary<string,string> xdict in list)
{
    foreach(var xkey in xdict.Keys)
    {
       Response.Write(xdict[xkey]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but this also is showing the same result two times.. like this 

images/piece2.pngLimited-time offer: Buy Office now, get the next version free.*Security & Updatesimages/piece2.pngLimited-time offer: Buy Office now, get the next version free.*Security & Updates

Comment: not sure what do u mean by two times.i think ur adding the dictionary twice otherwise this shud wrk fine

Answer (score 0):

I am feeling that you are using same object xmllist two times. That is the reason you are getting the image two times. Please try xmllist1 and xmllist2. All other answers for iterating through dictionary and arraylist looks correct to me. This is the reason that can be. So please try this.

```
 xmlList1.Add( "image" , "images/piece1.png" );
    xmlList1.Add( "description" , " Experience why entertainment is more amazing with Xbox."            );
    xmlList1.Add( "title" , "Downloads" );
    list.Add( xmlList1 );

    xmlList2.Add( "image" , "images/piece2.png" );
    xmlList2.Add( "description" , "Limited-time offer: Buy Office now, get the next version free.*" );
    xmlList2.Add( "title" , "Security & Updates" );
    list.Add( xmlList2 );
```

And then use the approach of CodeIgnoto.